# Convert date from UTC to CEST

Tags: javascript, sql, azure, time

I have this lines of code but how can I change to Europe CEST timezone? In this example it is `EventEnqueuedUtcTime`.

```
WITH machinelearning AS (
   SELECT EventEnqueuedUtcTime, temperature, humidity,
          machinelearning(temperature, humidity) as result
   from [YourInputAlias]
)
```

Comment: @jarlh CEST, sry

Answer (score 2):

[`AT TIME ZONE` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) could be utilized for that matter which:

> Converts an inputdate to the corresponding datetimeoffset value in the
>   target time zone

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, [EventEnqueuedUtcTime] AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'  AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time') AS [EventEnqueuedLocalTime]
FROM 
    [YourInputAlias]
```